# Efficient update statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, database-optimization

I have a large table (around 10M records) in a PostgreSQL 9.3 database, and I'm trying to run a simple update statement:

```
UPDATE mytable SET fresh = null WHERE fresh = true;
```

and it's been running for over an hour without any end in sight.

However, I know from:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE fresh = true;
```

which runs in a few seconds, that there are only 7000 records it would be effecting.

Why is my update taking so long? I have no triggers anywhere in my database, and the `fresh` column is indexed with:

```
CREATE INDEX mytable_fresh ON mytable USING btree (fresh);
```

Running `EXPLAIN UPDATE mytable SET fresh = null WHERE fresh = true` gives:

```
Update on mytable  (cost=0.00..455553.18 rows=9525759 width=167)
  ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..455553.18 rows=9525759 width=167)
        Filter: fresh
```

Am I correct that it's scanning all 9.5 million records and not using the index? If so, how do I fix this?

Edit: My `fresh` column is a nullable boolean type. I added a partial index for the `true` value and that drastically speed it up (22ms). Not sure why a partial index worked while the generic index was completely ignored. I'm finding this niche behavior in Postgres to be common and very frustrating with large data-warehousing projects.

Comment: Yes, it's not using the index.  Is that row count of 9M rows accurate? Let's see how your table is defined and any other indexes, just to be complete.  Also, do an explain on that `SELECT count` and make sure that that's using the index.

Comment: If `fresh` is a boolean column the optimizer might not consider it for using an index. Usually, having an index on a boolean makes no sense. Even if you consider NULL, you will have only 3 values: true, false and NULL which will result in 33% partition if you assume equal distribution. This is usually too much to have any advantage from an index. Does Postgres support Query hints or something similar?

Comment: By the way you can try a partial index which optimizes for the small partition, in your case the "fresh=true": `create index mytable_fresh on MyTable(fresh) where fresh is true;`

Comment: Whether it is scanning 9.5 million records or using an index doesn't matter, either way it should not take an hour.  You say you have no triggers, but do you have foreign keys?  What is your server doing:  CPU, IO, etc.?

Comment: In addition to not using the index due to very low [cardinality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28SQL_statements%29) as pointed by @Martin, it will have to update the index.

Comment: @MartinK., Yes, that drastically helped, but why is that even necessary? Why doesn't the normal index provide any benefit? Being able to truncate 66% of the records would still be tremendously faster than scanning all 10M records. I guess I'm going to have to define 3 partial indexes for each boolean column in Postgres that I want to filter by?

Comment: Did you check for locks blocking your update?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, it's running on my localhost and I ensured there was nothing else accessing the database.

Comment: Are there any foreign key constraints that refer to columns in `mytable`? If so, make sure the other end has an index.

Answer (score 0):

This text is a bit too long for a comment so i post it as an answer.

When investigating index usage don't think in terms of truncating records, think in terms of finding the matching records. It may look tempting to say "Hey, you can discard 66% of the records and the remaining set will be a piece of cake". But what the DBMS has to do is to find the records matching your search key. If there is no hint where to find a certain record, the DBMS has to scan the table and compare each record to the search key. Let's say each record fits in one page. This means the DBMS has to read `n` pages when the table has `n` records in a table scan.

The performance of the query improves if the DBMS can reduce the number of reads necessary to find all records matching the search key. This is done by an index which is like a table of content. The DBMS can look up in an index where to find certain records. Obviously, using the index will create additional page reads because the DBMS has to read the index pages too. Using the index makes only sense if `(number of index page reads + number of data page reads)<(number of page reads in table scan)`.

Imagine a table with 1000 records, let there be one boolean column and 333 records `true` and the rest `false`. Let's assume further you have an index with `depth=2`(the root and the first level). Finding the 333 records which are `true` requires 3 page reads per record: 2 index page reads and 1 data page read. As you can see, 333*3=999 which makes no difference to a table scan (1000 data page reads). If values are equally distributed, using the index will cause 500*3=1500 page reads compared to 1000 reads by table scan. In the Postgres documentation for partial indexes it says the threshold is ["a few percent of all the table rows"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/indexes-partial.html).

For low cardinality sets as you have in boolean columns, the optimizer (for Postgres it's query planner AFAIK) might consider usage of an index as bad choice by default. Using the partial index can override this choice. Here the DBMS will do an Index scan over the partial Index, so the estimate for reads would be `7000*(index tree depth+data pages per record)`.

Considering your case with over one hour execution time in the original scenario, it's possible that you have some memory or I/O issues in addition. Maybe there is a lot of paging while scanning the 9.5 million records and the Update will not only cause write access to data pages but also write access to the index pages and some of them will require overflow or underflow handling in the index tree causing more writes. The impact of those bottlenecks will be lower when using the partial index. Not only are there less page reads also the index which is updated is smaller.